# Stripe Embeddable Pricing Table - Specifying per-seat quantities

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm trying to use the [Stripe Pricing Table](https://stripe.com/docs/payments/checkout/pricing-table) for an app that has [per-seat billing](https://stripe.com/docs/products-prices/pricing-models#per-seat).

But, I want the app to pass the number of seats (`quantity`) to Stripe during the checkout flow, since my app already knows in this case how many seats the user needs. Is this possible? It seems like you can't specify it, and instead the user is given the option to manually specify the quantity, which is not what I want.

In Checkout you can do this by passing the "quantity" param, but I can't see how to get this to pass through from the pricing table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hmm I just found this configuration tooltip which seems to imply that it's not possible to disable. Darn!

[image]

Comment: That's correct, passing quantity to a Pricing Table is functionality that Stripe currently does not provide. I would recommend reaching out to them and letting them know that this is a feature that would be beneficial for your use case.